# Best way for learning OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I'm fixing to start on my second app which will be a game and I'm wanting to start learning OpenGL ES. I haven't been able to find many books out there that teach opengl es so I'm trying to figure out the best way to learn. I'm wanting to get to the level of almost an expert because I would like to be a full time mobile game developer one day.

I've seen Jeff LaMarches tutorials and I know about the NeHe tutorials. I'm personally thinking about buying the OpenGL blue book( link below ) and learning OpenGL first. Mainly because I've taken scientific visualization classes in college but didn't use opengl or directx and I need to learn more about the basics.

So, for those still with me what would be some advice on learning OpenGL ES?

[http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-SuperBible-Comprehensive-Tutorial-Reference/dp/0321498828/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1260995048&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321498828)

Answer (score 7):

The fastest way to learn is to dive in. Studying will only get you so far, so I suggest skipping that step entirely. I learn best working on an actual project. If you don't have one in mind, may I suggest a 3D rendered version of Tetris?

As long as you build test rigs that are neither too ambitious nor too simplistic, you can develop parts of your core engine as you learn. You also won't spend too much time reading about hyperspheres unless you actually need to.

If you're wondering where to start, the answer is anywhere. If you get stuck, there's this site and a heap of tutorials.